# Is reflection my best option here?

Tags: java, reflection, spring-mvc

We allow users to set some preferences in our web application.  When they login to certain sites, they are allowed to do/see different screens vs. when they are in another site.  One of our requirements is that we hide preferences on the page which they can't access in the currently logged in site.  Currently we are using Spring MVC to handle these requests.

Here is a simplified example of our POJO:

```
public class Preferences {
  boolean prefA; //Valid when can do A
  String prefB;  //Valid when can do B
  Integer prefC; //Valid when can do C
  ....
  Long prefZ;    //Valid when can do Z
}
```

Here is the controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "preferences.xhtml")
public ModelAndView updateRequestPreferences(@ModelAttribute(USER_PREFERENCES) final Preference preferences, final BindingResult results)
{
  return updatePreferences(preferences, results);
}
```

Currently updatePreferences does reflection, and ensures that the value is not null before it persists the input preferences -- This is due to Spring MVC creating a new instance of Preferences and then populating the values with what was on the UI.

We could do the following in the setter of the preferences:

```
public void setPreferences(Preferences preferences) {
  if (preferences.getPrefA() != null) {
    this.preferences.setPrefA(preferences.getPrefA());
  }
  if (preferences.getPrefB() != null) {
    this.preferences.setPrefB(preferences.getPrefB());
  } 
  ...
  if (preferences.getPrefZ() != null) {
    this.preferences.setPrefZ(preferences.getPrefZ());
  }
}
```

It would get unwieldy even with a helper function for all the checks in the setter method (and seems like an easy step to forget when a new preference is created); at the same time reflection seems like a cop out.  Is there a better way to refactor this?

Comment: Reflection/Introspection is not a cop out.  It's good design!

Comment: Depending on what is in your Preferences object, would good old fashioned name/value pairs work?

Comment: @Paul Then we'd need yet another blob in the DB to store the values (which if you look at one of my previous questions) I'd rather avoid.  I got a +1 for "extends BadDBDesign"...

Comment: Reflection is fine then. After all, Spring will have used it to populate your `Preferences` object in the first place! If you don't want twice the reflection, then you'll have to get lower level and use the parameters from the HttpServletRequest directly.

Comment: I think reflection is not the way to go. The best solution is to find a dynamic way to store preference data. I would suggest using  a format like Json and using Groovy to make sense of the Dynamic Json sent from the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure Spring MVC to populate fields of a preexisting object rather than to create a new one.

For example, you can use `@SessionAttributes(USER_PREFERENCES)` in order to store an instance of `Preferences` in a session between rendering a form and processing its submit.

Another approach is to load new instance of `Preferences` from the database as an implicit model attribute:

```
@ModelAttribute(USER_PREFERENCES)
public Preferences loadPreferences(@RequestParam("key") String key) {
    return loadPreferencesByKey(key);
}
```

Note that in all cases (and your original approach needs it as well) you need to specify a set of allowed fields in `@InitBinder` method, to prevent malicious user from modifying fields that was not rendered in a form:

```
@InitBinder(USER_PREFERENCES)
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder b) {
    b.setAllowedFields("prefA", "prefB");
}
```